# Is there any difference between my lecturer's while loop and my while loop?

Tags: c

My lecturer's method for while loop is,for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  int mark;
  mark = 0;
  while (mark !=100){
    printf("Please input your mark");
    scanf("%i",&mark);
    if (mark <= 50){
      printf("You need to practice more");
    }
    else if (mark==100){
      printf("You are too good. Nothing to say to you. Keep it up");
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

And this is my method for while loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  int mark;
  printf("Please input your mark");
  scanf("%i",&mark);
  while (mark !=100){
    if (mark <= 50){
      printf("You need to practice more");
    }
    printf("Please input your mark");
    scanf("%i",&mark);

  }
if (mark==100){
   printf("You are too good. Nothing to say to you. Keep it up");
}

return 0;
}
```

Based on the result of both. I see there is no difference. But is mine accepted?

Comment: Step through the code yourself, either by hand or with a debugger, and see that there is no effective difference. In fact, with your code, the `if` statement is unnecessary; the only way out of the loop is mark==100.

Comment: Both of you should check the return value from scanf

Comment: Your lecturer's version needs less statements, so is more clean. However, a `do {...}while` loop could even be better as it needs no initialization of `mark`.

Comment: Your method duplicates code. If you wanted to change the message, variable name, or what you're looking for you'd need to do it in 2 places which is more error prone.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Thank you so much. Just now i wanted to do that also but then i want to make it clearer hihi. Thank you so much !!!

Comment: @RetiredNinja oh i see so basically Mine is more complicated than of my lecturer's one. Thank you

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Oh i see. Thank you so Much!

Comment: Why do not use the debugger or the assembly​ listing to see it. Btw if after the loop is not needed.. both examples are too trivial, but even in this triviality you have archived the effect of the "banana code". Your version is much worse illogical, showing that you do not understand the code, with the code duplications

Comment: @PeterJ_01 While I agree with your comment, I think describing the `if` as unneeded might be misleading. I understand that you mean there is no need to check for the condition before printing the message, but the OP could read it as meaning they don't need that section at all :)

Comment: @FluffyKitten in his example while loops until mark != 100. When it stops mark is guaranteed to be 100 as this value breaks this loop. So checking if mark ==100 just after the loop which executes when mark!=100 is not needed and I bet that the good optimising compiler will remove this check anyway unless the mark is volatile

Comment: @PeterJ_01 I'd updated my previous comment to clarify what I was trying to say before you replied :)

Comment: I think the `if` is appropriate. It shows intent which is important for others reading the code, and if the condition for exiting the loop ever changes it may prevent a bug.

Comment: The messages should end with newlines.  The `more` gets mixed up with the prompt.  The code should probably consider what happens if the mark is negative, or bigger than 100.  (Someone else pointed out that the code should test the return value from `scanf()`.)  I'd seriously consider writing and using a 'prompt for int' function that returns a 'value read or EOF' indication and that sets a pointer argument to the value that was read.  You could then use `while (prompt_for_int("Please input your mark", &mark) != EOF && mark != 100)` for the loop condition.

Answer (score 2):

A third option (do ... while()). Also cleaned up the strings. The continue avoids a redundant compare, although an optimizing compiler may add the equivalent of a continue during the compilation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int mark;
    do {
        printf("Please input your mark: ");
        scanf("%i", &mark);
        if (mark <= 50) {
            printf("You need to practice more.\n");
            continue;   /* optimizing compiler may already do this */
        }
    } while (mark != 100);
    printf("You are too good. Nothing to say to you. Keep it up.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I edited your code to add the check that scanf read a number.

Comment: The current version of the code needs `mark` to be initialized in case `scanf` fails and no assignment took place.

Comment: Automatic variable `mark` could initially be 100. If `scanf` fails and no assigment to `mark` took place then it will conclude `"You are too good."` But we are nitpicking; it is the illustration of the do-while loop that is important.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie - if no assignment takes place, then scanf usually won't advance it's "file pointer", so it won't read further input and instead just continue to fail. I wasn't trying to fix the original code to handle this situation. The simplest fix would be to check if scanf didn't return a 1 and if not, print an error message and exit (return). If there was an error scanf("%*[^\n]"); could be used to scan up to newline, getting past the invalid input, along with feof(stdin) to check for eof incase redirected input. I think it would be better to use fgets() and sscanf().

Answer (score -1):

There is no semantic difference between your code and your lecture's code, except you just added extra if statement which actually makes the code longer.

Comment: this is not the issue